# Azure CloudOperationResponse<CloudQueueMessage> response issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to pop message from the queue. ( Windows Phone 7 ) But unfortunately getting such error inside `CloudOperationResponse<CloudQueueMessage> response` object:

`Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:75c52c29-a325-44a4-9cc4-3203fb99fb47
Time:2012-07-11T09:43:56.6042490Z`

[image]

Any one has any ideas why it happens? Thank you in advance!

```
    public StorageInitializer()
    {
           var resolver = new CloudStorageClientResolverAccountAndKey(
           new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("ACCNAME", "KEY"),
           new Uri("http://ACCNAME.blob.core.windows.net"),
           new Uri("http://ACCNAME.queue.core.windows.net"),
           new Uri("http://ACCNAME.table.core.windows.net"),
           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher);

           CloudStorageContext.Current.Resolver = resolver;
    }


    public void FetchMsg()
    {

        CloudQueueClient queueClient = CloudStorageContext.Current.Resolver.CreateCloudQueueClient() as CloudQueueClient;
        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queueout");

        queue.GetMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), OnMessageReturned);

    }

    private void OnMessageReturned(CloudOperationResponse<CloudQueueMessage> response)
    { 
        string str = response.Response.AsString;
    }
```

Comment: Did you verify if your queue exists?

Comment: Yes, I do verification. It exist! But for some reason I still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see the exact problem with WP7.1 Emulator and here are my investigation:

With Desktop the GetMessage from Queue shows the following parameters:

[image]

With WP7 Emulator I see some other parameters:

[image]

The Error shows that the GetMessage request is bad so your code is fine to collect the message but the code which makes the call to getMessage needs some work. If u have access to that you sure can debug it to resolve the problem.